# Login redirect service handle error on constructor parameters

Tags: symfony, service, symfony-2.2

I followed this tutorial to set up a redirect to the last page after login: http://www.reecefowell.com/2011/10/26/redirecting-on-loginlogout-in-symfony2-using-loginhandlers/

My services.yml

```
parameters:
    assinatura_user_security.component.login_success_handler.class: Assinatura\UserBundle\Component\LoginSuccessHandler

services:
     assinatura_user_security.component.login_success_handler:
        class:  %assinatura_user_security.component.login_success_handler.class%
        arguments:  [@service_container, @router, @security.context]
        tags:
            - { name: 'monolog.logger', channel: 'security' }
```

security.yml

```
form_login:
                login_path: usuario_login
                check_path: usuario_login_check
                success_handler: assinatura_user_security.component.login_success_handler
```

my class:

```
<?php

namespace Assinatura\UserBundle\Component;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;

class LoginSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{

    protected $router;
    protected $security;

    public function __construct(Router $router, SecurityContext $security)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {

        $referer_url = $request->headers->get('referer');

        $response = new RedirectResponse($referer_url);


        return $response;
    }

}
```

and the error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Assinatura\UserBundle\Component\LoginSuccessHandler::__construct()
>   must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Routing\Router, instance of
>   appDevDebugProjectContainer given, called in
>   /var/www/assinatura/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on
>   line 131 and defined in
>   /var/www/assinatura/src/Assinatura/UserBundle/Component/LoginSuccessHandler.php
>   line 18

my symfony version is 2.2

i want to redirect to same page when are not logged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this solution (new in 2.1)

```
frontend:
            pattern:        ^/*
            provider:       usuarios
            anonymous:      ~
            form_login:
                login_path: usuario_login
                check_path: usuario_login_check
                use_referer:        true
            logout:
                path:       usuario_logout
            remember_me:
                key:        userassinatura2013
                lifetime:   604800
```

the 'use_referer' set to be used on redirect after login

Answer (score 3):

Try change this in `services.yml`, from `arguments:    [@service_container, @router, @security.context]` to `arguments:  [@router, @security.context]`.

```
services:
     assinatura_user_security.component.login_success_handler:
        class:  %assinatura_user_security.component.login_success_handler.class%
        arguments:  [@router, @security.context]
        tags:
            - { name: 'monolog.logger', channel: 'security' }
```